# Laravel - How do I get a named route from a config file?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a few named routes in the `routes.php` file which I can build the url to via the global `route('routename',[args])`. However how can I do this in a config file?

I've tried `URL::route('name')`, and also `route('name')` and receive the error: `Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class log does not exist in /var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:734`

Comment: Could you show some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When laravel is bootstraping your application to process the request, the config files are not able to call functions declared in autoloaded classes, because they are not loaded already. I suggest to you setting the route's name:

```
//config/custom.php
'checkout' => 'shop.checkout'
```

Then, in your controllers or views, for example, you build your routes using the config value:

```
$url = route(config('custom.checkout'));
```