# Use named route in laravel config files

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, multilingual

Im trying to use a named route in laravel service.php config file
but it error that the Route is not defined even it is.

routes/web.php:

```
Route::get('social/{provider}/callback', 'Auth\SocialAuthController@handleProviderCallback')
->name('social.callback');
```

service.php:

```
'facebook' => [
    'client_id' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'client_secret' => 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY',
    'redirect' => route('social.callback', 'facebook'),
],
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel - How do I get a named route from a config file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39182772/laravel-how-do-i-get-a-named-route-from-a-config-file)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39182772/laravel-how-do-i-get-a-named-route-from-a-config-file?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Configuration is typically used to bootstrap the application and bootstrapping the application involves registering the routes. It is a bit of a circular dependency to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 4):

You should try this:

Your config file

```
return [
    'url' => 'admin.index',
]
```

Your blade file

```
<a href="{!! route(config('yourConfig.url')) !!}">Admin</a>
```

Updated answer:

OR you should set your parameters in .env file and put .env file variable in config file and access it like:

```
FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET=YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
CALLBACK_URL=http://www.your_url.com/social/handle/facebook
```

Comment: this is not what im trying to do, i want to use the route method inside a config file

Answer (score 2):

We can't use laravel functions in config files as they are loaded before Laravel libraries

Just save route and parameter as a String

```
'facebook' => [
    'client_id'     => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'client_secret' => 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY',
    'redirect'      => [ 
        'url' => 'social.callback',
        'parameter' => 'facebook'
    ]
]
```